# Is an NFS export being used by an external system?

Tags: 18.04, bash, mount, nfs

System A (Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS) exports a directory for NFS mounting by systems B, C, or D.  On A (the server) is there a way to tell whether any of the other systems currently has the directory mounted?

The objective is to avoid shutting down A if any of B, C, or D have mounted the exported directory.

An automated (shell scripted) means of doing so would be ideal, but manual is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct NFS utils (provided by `nfs-utils`) to list the clients connected to NFS server (mounts exported directories).

However, if NFSv4 is used, on the NFS server side clients can easily be identified using `ss` or `netstat` because it uses only 1 port 2049 for both UDP and TCP:

Examples

`netstat -naptule | grep :2049`

```bsh
root@n54l:~# exportfs -rav
exporting 192.168.1.0/24:/srv/oops

root@n54l:~# netstat -naptule | grep :2049
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          32620      -                 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.123:2049      192.168.1.150:730       ESTABLISHED 0          94689      -                 
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          32631      -
```

`ss -tuna | grep :2049`

```bsh
root@n54l:~# ss -tuna | grep :2049
tcp   LISTEN     0      64                0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*
tcp   ESTAB      0      0           192.168.1.123:2049      192.168.1.150:730
tcp   LISTEN     0      64                   [::]:2049               [::]:*
```

We can see the NFS server 192.168.1.123, there was 1 client 192.168.1.150 connected to it.

Combination of either command with text processing (grep, cut, awk, sed, etc.) can assemble a shell script to achieve what you want at ease.

> NOTE: `nfsstat` and `nfsiostat` (client side) may provide some insight but the results/stats are not direct.

Answer (score 0):

From the No Good Deed Goes Unpunished Department, here is a simple script which accomplishes my mission.  Thanks again to Terry Wang.  The script which calls this enters a perpetual "do" loop which attempts shutown and sleeps for a few minutes.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # Check for open Samba share.
    # All shares are named "share" something,
    # so grep for "share" is usable

    smbstatus | grep -i share > /dev/nul
    samba=$?

    # Check for open NFS mount.
    # Grep for port 2049, then
    # grep that for "ESTAB"

    netstat -naptule | grep :2049 | grep ESTAB > /dev/nul
    nfs=$?

    # If either came back zero, something is active.

    if [[ $samba != 0 && $nfs != 0 ]]; then
       shutdown -h now
    fi
```